# Should I use utf8_unicode_ci or utf8_slovak_ci?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

I was using `utf8_slovak_ci` collation until now, but I read that [`utf8_unicode_ci` sorts very wide range of languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci). Does it mean, I do not need to use separate collation for every language and I can simply always use `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Lets say all content on my website is in **Slovak language** - is there difference between using `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8_slovak_ci`?

I use MariaDB 5.5 (they say it is functionaly identical to MySQL 5.5).

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to answer you because I do not know `utf8_slovak_ci` nor the slovak language, but I will tell you how I would test it myself:

Take an extensive list of words containing "problematic" (as in, non-existant in the English alphabet) letter representations (as far as I know, letters in your language containing ˇ, ´, ¨ and ˆ, maybe others)- Please forgive my ignorance of your language.

Sort them and compare them using the 2 potential collations, like this:

```
SELECT word FROM test_table ORDER BY word COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci;
SELECT word FROM test_table ORDER BY word COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

SELECT word FROM test_table WHERE word like 'ž%' COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci;
SELECT word FROM test_table WHERE word like 'ž%' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Check for differences between them, and with the common orthography rules.

If you get similar results, they should be equivalent, and you should think whether you want to also use the collation rules of the other languages (even if your site is only Slovak, I may register there as "jynus from Logroño", which contains a "problematic" character). In that case, use the unicode version, and remember that at any time you can change the collation of comparisons for particular queries. For example:

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'á' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 'a' = 'á' COLLATE utf8_bin;
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 'a' = 'á' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  | 'a' = 'á' COLLATE utf8_bin  |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|                                  1 |                           0 |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: For example, this is a problem for my mother tongue (Spanish): `mysql> SELECT 'ñ' = 'n' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 'ñ' = 'n' COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;`

Comment: From what you say, I understand that utf8_unicode_ci is only what makes sense at all. utf8_LANGUAGE_ci had sense only because there was no utf8_unicode_ci before. Right?

Comment: @Martin Not necessarily- In my previous comment, I showed an example query where the Spanish collation gives a right orthographic result (n is different from ñ and one should be sorted before another), while the unicode one gives a generic result (n equivalent to ñ). In many cases, collation is not so important, a specific collation can be used for important comparisons or many times they are done at application side with custom algorithms. When in doubt, use the unicode one, but I firmly recommend you to test it by yourself.

Comment: I created table with single column and I filled it with all letters I could imagine in my language. Both slovak and unicode sorted it in same way.

But 'ž' = 'z' is same in unicode and different letter in Slovak.

So, now I need to answer question - do I want 'ñ' and 'n' (or other letters similar in this way) to act as same or act as different letters?

Comment: @Martin That is not a MySQL question -it is your choice, or the application developer's to make the application work well with the application.